# How to block response on fastapi until script is ran?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a fastapi endpoint that calls a python script but has two problems on GCP:

1. it always give a success code (because it's not blocking)
2. The instances is always running as cloud rundoesn't know when to turn it off(because it's not blocking).

I think the problem is blocking :-)

Here's a sample of my code:

```
async def curve_builder(secret: str):
    os.system("python3 scripts/my_script.py")     
    return {"succcess": True, "status": "Batch job completed"}
```

Is there a way to let the script and then return a success/fail message once it's done? I'm not sure how to block it, it seems to just return a success as soon as the command is executed.

I'm not sure if this is specific to fastapi or general python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking operations could hang up your current worker. When you want to execute blocking code over a coroutine, send its logic to a executor.

1. Get the event loop

```py
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
```

2. Any blocking code must go out of your coroutine. So, your current worker will be able to execute other coroutines.

```py
await loop.run_in_executor(None, func)
```

For your case, the final result will be:

```py
async def curve_builder(secret: str):
  loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
  result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: os.system("python3 scripts/my_script.py"))
  return {"status": result}
```

You can read further information in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Comment: Wow thank you. I tried to run it and it seems to work but returns a success message right away. Is there a way to capture a failure ? I use cloud scheduler so if it returns a 200 message then scheduler thinks it worked fine and won’t retry. Can I pipe the command to something like $? To get the status of the script and return a error for a non 0 response?

Comment: @Lostsoul In the above example, `result` variable receives the return variable of the `os.system` method which is the return code of your script (and it should be good enough for your case). Anyway, if you need a better control, consider to replace `os.system` method to another as `subprocess.call`. Also, about your command, you are trying to run a python script, but you can import its path and use it natively instead of using `os.system` or `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Thank you, BeardOverflow! The scripts are able to run independently and are simply just scripts(no classes), etc. They basically call a DB, export the data, do some modifications and then save it into another location. The reason we did it this way was because there's a different team building it and they aren't aware of our api that triggers the job. 

If I import the script, could I trigger it by just importing it?

Comment: @Lostsoul Yes, you could trigger it. Import it as a library and call to its main function later.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Assign the ‘os.system()’ call to a variable. The exit code of your script is assigned, so it will wait till it finished, despite being a async method you are working from.</s>

The answer was wrong, I've tested an example setup but could not reproduce the issue.

Script1:

```py
import os
import asyncio

async def method1():
    print("Start of method1")
    os.system("python /path/to/other/script/script2.py")
    print("End of method1")

print("start script1")
asyncio.run(method1())
print("end script1")
```

Script2:

```py
import asyncio

async def method2():
    print("Start method2")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("End method2")

print("start async script2")
asyncio.run(method2())
print("end async script2")
```

Output:

```
start script1
Start of method1
start async script2
Start method2
End method2
End async script2
End of method
end script1
```

Comment: Can you show me a example? I'm not sure I understand:
var = 'os.system("python3 scripts/my_script.py") '

Wouldn't that save it as a text?

Comment: Sorry my answer was incorrect, I tested it locally and it didn't work as expected. In my test, the calling method (in your example, `curve_builder()`) waits for the script to finish before it returns. I don't know why it doesn't in your case, might have to do with running in GCP? Have you confirmed that the script itself is being called? Can you wrap the contents of the script into a method and call that directly?